# How to use jenkins to declare BUILD_NUMBER environment variable in gradle?

Tags: gradle

```
    InterfaceVersion = Interface-Version
    Interface-Version = V2  
         //     property environment = env
     label = ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} 
     ReleaseVersion = Release-Version
     Release-Version = ${env.release_version}
```

This is what I have in my gradle.properties file. I know I am doing it wrong. How can I make it display a build_number and release_version??

Answer (score 0):

The values in `gradle.properties` files are not interpolated by default. For this you would need to use some Gradle plugin that does it, or you have to do it manually. The default Gradle behaviour just parses them as plain old properties files. If you know which ones should have the dynamic values, just set them in your `build.gradle` file instead of in `gradle.properties`, the effect will be the same. If you need the dynamicness of being able to use it in the `gradle.properties` files, either use a plugin that does such interpolations or manually evaluate each value as a Groovy expression so that the placeholders get replaced.

You can search through the list of available plugins on the [Gradle Plugins Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org). E. g. [com.admc.javaPropFile](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.admc.javaPropFile) is a candidate you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.0.0.13"
    }
```

And to read the atribute:

```
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Comment: Where would I insert that script? in my build.xml or gradle.properties

Comment: In gradle properties:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
   ...
}


 By the way, the version Code is used when you do a signed APK and you will load on Google Play store, Each time you want to do an update you must to increment this number.

Comment: Is there a way where I don't have to hardcode the version #

Comment: No, you cant, and google play will read the same field from your gradle file. That mean google want  this practice. This is a picture from my Google Play developer console:

https://gyazo.com/9ea47a9973034ce2606bcd8129dbecb1

Can you see the versionCode and versionName?

Comment: I see. so VersionCode is basically my "Release-Version" and VersionName is basically my "Build_Number"?

Comment: We could say that yes. But versionCode must be a number between 1...N. Your versionName is a string in the end. And versionCode cant be lower than your older versionNames on play store. Check my picture and you will realize that each new versionCode is higher than the olders one