# Unable to access BUILD_NUMBER environment variable of jenkins in PHP and phing

Tags: php, jenkins, phing

**Via entry point file**

I invoke a php script from jenkins, using the "Execute shell" section -

```
php entry.php branch_name_${branch_name} deployment_group_${deployment_group} rollback_${rollback} last_successful_revision_${last_successful_revision} sanity_check_duration_start_time_delay_sec_${sanity_check_duration_start_time_delay_sec} sanity_check_duration_end_time_delay_sec_${sanity_check_duration_end_time_delay_sec}
```

I tried accessing the jenkins build number there, but it was not available -

```
$build_number = exec(${BUILD_NUMBER});
file_put_contents('/home/jenkins/deployment_beta/phing/new_test_sandeepan.txt', "\n Build number is ".$build_number, FILE_APPEND);
```

Log lin in that file shows -

```
 Build number is
```

**Via phing xml file**

I also tried accessing it in a phing xml file -

```
<appspecFileModifications buildName="${BUILD_NUMBER}" />
```

This xml file is invoked via the above mentioned entry file (php script), like this -

```
$last_output = exec("phing -q -Dbranch_name=".$branchName, $output);
```

I checked other questions like - 
[How to use jenkins to declare BUILD_NUMBER environment variable in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664548/how-to-use-jenkins-to-declare-build-number-environment-variable-in-gradle)
[Jenkins - How to access BUILD_NUMBER environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179447/jenkins-how-to-access-build-number-environment-variable)

Comment: Why do you `exec`ute the build number?

Comment: Should I have added echo inside the exec? Anyway, I have also tried this in the entry point php file - `$last_output = exec("phing -q  -Dbuild_number=${BUILD_NUMBER}", $output);`

Comment: No, the exec makes no sense. Environment variables should be in [$_ENV](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)

Comment: I tried dumping the $_ENV variable, but it shows empty - `file_put_contents('/home/jenkins/deployment_beta/phing/new_test_sandeepan.txt', "\n Build number is ".$_ENV['BUILD_NUMBER']." and all env vars are ".print_r($_ENV,1)."\n", FILE_APPEND);`. Output - ` Build number is  and all env vars are Array
(
)`

Comment: Ok I got it using getent(). Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to add this to an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

With Phing you would be able to get environment variables with a prefixed [`env.`](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#sec.builtinprops)

```
    <appspecFileModifications buildName="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}" />
```

All variables from `$_SERVER` are available in this way.